# Is $|G|$ the cardinality or order of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

Is $|G|$ one or the other or both? If it is both then how are you supposed to tell the difference between what the writer is trying to display.

Comment: What *is* the difference?

Comment: They are the exact same thing.  Note that the order of a group _element_ is not the same thing.

Comment: Well some authors define groups as an ordered pair or ordered triple so the cardinality would be something else, but that's just a technicality and everyone will understand what you mean when you talk about the cardinality of a group.

Comment: isnt cardinality how many elements are in the set and the order is how many times it takes to get a set to the identity with itself under its operation?

Comment: As noted above, order of a group element can be different from order of a group

Comment: The order of an *element* is how many times it takes to get that *element* to the identity *element* by powering it with the group operation. This definition applies to elements, not to sets. What do you think it would even *mean* to get the identity from *a set* with the operation?

Comment: If $G$ is a group, then $GG=\{xy\mid x,y\in G\}$ is always equal to $G$, so you would never "get it to the identity under its operations". That definition would not make sense.

Answer (score 5):

In *most* places, it would be the cardinality of the underlying set of $G$, which is also the same thing as "the order of the group $G$". They are the same thing, and so an author would not need to have you tell "the difference" between the two uses: the order of a group is the cardinality of its underlying set, *by definition*.

(It's possible you may be confusing "order of the group" with "exponent of the group". We say a group $G$ has order $n$ if it has exactly $n$ elements. We say a group $G$ has *exponent* $n$ if for every $g\in G$, $g^n=e$; that is, every element has exponent $n$; equivalently, every element has *order* dividing $n$.)

*However*, you want to be careful. Some authors may use it to denote something *entirely different*; but if that is the case, they will be very upfront and explcit about this nonstandard use.

For example, one very good book I know of that does this is George Bergman's [An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/245/); he is very careful to distinguish between an algebra and its underlying set, and for reasons perhaps a bit boring to go into (including his original choice of typsetting software), he uses $|A|$ to denote the underlying set of the structure $A$. Thus, a group $G$ is an ordered $4$-tuple, $G = (|G|,\mu,\iota,e)$, where $|G|$ is a set, $\mu$ is a binary operation of $|G|$ (corresponding to multiplication), $\iota$ is a unary operation on $|G|$ (correspoding to the inverse of an element) and $e$ is a nullary/zeroary operation on $|G|$ (yielding the identity element) which satisfy certain identities. So here $|G|$ denotes the underlying set of the group, with the group being the whole $4$-tuple of information that defines a group as a universal algebra. But he is explicit about this and about the clash with the usual meaning.

(For those wondering, he uses $\mathrm{card}(A)$ for the cardinality of a set).